# For magento 2.3.4, what is the best option to adopt PayPal Payments Pro (or) PayPal Payments Advanced

Tags: paypal, magento2.3.4

For my US customer which is the best option to adopt? PayPal Payments Pro or PayPal Payments Advanced?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good comparison of the two: https://jilt.com/blog/paypal-comparison-which-paypal-service/

In terms of PCI, with PayPal Advanced, the customer is actually inputting their card details on a PayPal hosted page embedded in your site, so it lessens your PCI requirements.

If you look at the pricing at: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced

you'll see the bigest difference is with Pro, you get a virtual terminal to run card numbers manually, whereas with Advanced, you do not. Advanced is not a full featured gateway service like Pro. If you don't need a virtual terminal, Advanced is the way to go for simpler PCI requirements.